# What font is this? Font with curved A's?

Tags: font-identification

I'm trying to identify the font used in this heading from one of my son's DVDs:

[image]

Whatthefont wasn't even close. Identifont wasn't either. Not one of the fonts either suggested had curved lines on the A and l. The i looks almost like Futura Extra Bold, but it's missing the whimsical curves and many of the letter forms look totally different. Anyone have any ideas what this is? Or if not, something similar?

Comment: What did you use as input image for Whatthefont and Identifont? Could you add that here? The recognition may well have failed because it was not suitable prepared.

Answer (score 9):

The font is close to [LasVegasJackPot](http://www.houseind.com/fonts/lasvegasfonts)

[image]

Comment: Totally! Looks like the final result was a bit stretch horizontally.

Comment: Or compressed vertically! :) No question this is the correct face, though.